# postgresql materialized views taking forever to refresh in a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I wanted to use a function to call everyday on a schedule to materialize multiple views. It would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_my_views()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    -- Array of view names in the order they should be refreshed
    views text[] := ARRAY[
        'view1',
        'view2',
        'view3'
        -- ... add more view names here as needed
    ];
    view_name text;
    start_time timestamp;
    end_time timestamp;
BEGIN
    -- Iterate over each view name in the array
    FOREACH view_name IN ARRAY views LOOP
        -- Log the start of the refresh operation
        RAISE NOTICE 'Starting refresh of %', view_name;
        
        -- Start the timer
        start_time := current_timestamp;

        -- Refresh the materialized view
        EXECUTE format('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY %s', view_name);
        
        -- Stop the timer
        end_time := current_timestamp;

        -- Log the completion of the refresh operation and the time taken
        RAISE NOTICE 'Completed refresh of % (Time: %)', 
                      view_name, age(end_time, start_time);
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$;
```

This function however is taking more than 12 hours to run, it seems like after a while I can't event `pg_terminate_backend` it by its PID, and I can't run another command to refresh any of these views in parallel. The views are fast to create, and even the longest one to refresh shouldn't take more than 15 minutes.
I am also not seeing the messages for the `RAISE NOTICE` statements.

It should just print the times, take around 30min at most and be done with it.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your system is overloaded, Postgresql is built to run outside of your computer and it is imported into your commandline. Make sure you check the Postgresql log and read the output.
Tools lik 'iostat' can help pinpoint the problem.
Check the system logs too.

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same problem. Refreshing the materialized views just by themselves (outside a function) works within 10s, inside the function they never finished or just took many many hours. Interestingly that time even increased over time, which I could see by a logging table.
And,  like in your case, even the notices didn't get executed.
I have a staging system with the same data, where it works perfectly fine.

I could solve the problem by doing an update on the involved tables. This is however, not explaining the cause of the issue, but it helped as a workaround

This is really a strange problem and I would appreciate any further hints to the underlying cause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour).